# Can I use one Examples for multiple Scenario Outline

Tags: cucumber, feature-extraction, python-behave

This is the code I am using:

```
Scenario Outline: Fill <answers> for Shares
  When Select one of "<answers>" from Shares
  Then One of the Shares dropdown "<answers>" will be visible

 Scenario Outline: Fill <answers> for Forex
  When Select one of "<answers>" from Forex
  Then One of the Forex dropdown "<answers>" will be visible

Examples:
  | answers    |
  | Frequently |
  | Sometimes  |
  | No         |
```

But I got error that first Scenario Outline do not have Examples.
Point is: this Examples are repeated, so I am asking can I use one Examples table for multiple Scenario Outlines?

Comment: You might move the `Shares|Forex` as a value column in the `Examples` section.

Answer (score -1):

Scenario outline must have example.
You can use below single scenario outline with all options.

```
Scenario Outline: Fill <answers> for Forex
  When Select one of "<answers>" from <type>
  Then One of the Forex dropdown "<answers>" will be visible
Examples:
  |type   | answers    |
  |forex  | Frequently |
  |forex  | Sometimes  |
  |forex  | No         |
  |shares | Frequently |
  |shares | Sometimes  |
  |shares | No         |
```